# findAncestorStateOfType was call on null Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to navigate after logging in with the cell number, everything works fine, however, in the part of wanting to navigate, I am getting an error, and it is the following Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null .

This is the portion of the code that is giving me an error

```
void verifyOTPAndLogin({String smsCode, BuildContext context}) async {
 _authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
 verificationId: actualCode, smsCode: smsCode);
 final FirebaseUser user =
  (await _auth.signInWithCredential(_authCredential)).user;
  _user = user;
  LoginState().loginPhone(user, context);
   if (_user != null) {
    Navigator.push(
     context, 
     MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context)=> TasksPage()
    )
   );
  } else {
   Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context)=> LoginPage()
    )
    );
  }
  _loggedIn = true;
  notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Is the `context` getting passed to `verifyOTPAndLogin` ?

Comment: Yes of course, if I'm passing it to

Comment: signIn(localizations) async {
    if (code.length != 6) {
      _showSnackBar(localizations.t('verify.snackBarText1'),);
    }
    Provider.of<PhoneAuthDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .verifyOTPAndLogin(smsCode: code, context: context);
        
  }